# Magento: Placing Order doesn't redirect to success page

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I have a little problem with placing order button on magento. For some reasons when I complete a order and click "Place Order" it doesn't redirect the page in a success page (or even elsewhere) it just stays in the checkout page with all the products still inside (image https://i.stack.imgur.com/74I3X.png this is what happen when I click the place order button)

I don't really know where to modify the redirect to another page.

This is the code for the /Checkout/controllers/onepagecontroller.php

```
  /**
 * Order success action
 */
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Check from the browser console if there is any kind of javascript error

Comment: I'll try, do you think it's possible that I have a javascript error and still the order goes on? I mean, the only problem is that I can't see the Success page but still I receive the email saying that my order is completed

Edit: I checked and the only errors that I get is about 2 images that cannot be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** There was a problem with the file in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/core/email/template.php (there was a character that stopped the page)

Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have php-mbscript enabled in your server.

Magento 1.9.x version requires this needs to be turned on if it is disabled

For more information you can read following post

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62744/place-order-button-doesnt-go-to-success-confirmation-page-1-9-1-0

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I have another website on the same server with a default theme that goes directly in the success page. So I think it's purely a theme problem.